# Validate input using single method or per setter

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, logic

I've just started out with test-driven development and I was wondering which practice is best when it comes to validating properties that are set using user-input. I'm not sure which method is preferrable or even best.

Below are two example methods of doing this.

If there is a guru out there that could shed some light on the subject I'd be very grateful!

### Method: one validation method to rule them all

Consider the following: I have a class with getters and setters for properties. The first approach is validating all set properties using a single method.

```
/**
 * @returns bool TRUE if validates, FALSE if not
 */
public function validate()
{
// validate all set properties here
}
```

Testing wise I need to take into account every single possible option for each property that needs to be validated, resulting in something like this in my Unit test:

```
$this->oObject->setActionCodeGroupID(12);
$this->oObject->setFilename('filename.txt');
$this->oObject->setAmount(10000);
$this->oObject->setMaxUsage(10);
$this->oObject->setMinLength(9);
$this->oObject->setMaxLength(12);
$this->oObject->setPrefix('TM_');

$this->assertTrue($this->oObject->validate());

$this->oObject->setActionCodeGroupID(0);
$this->assertFalse($this->oObject->validate());
$this->oObject->setActionCodeGroupID(12);

$this->oObject->setFilename('');
$this->assertFalse($this->oObject->validate());
$this->oObject->setFilename('filename.txt');

$this->oObject->setAmount(0);
$this->assertFalse($this->oObject->validate());
$this->oObject->setAmount(10000);

$this->oObject->setMaxUsage(0);
$this->assertFalse($this->oObject->validate());
$this->oObject->setMaxUsage(10);

...
```

### Method 2: Validate input in setter

This method basically does what the heading says, it (if necessary) validates the input straight away. If the input doesn't validate an exception will be thrown.

```
public function setCodeGroup(CodeGroup $oCodeGroup)
{
    if (!($oCodeGroup instanceof CodeGroup)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Expected instance of CodeGroup, got '. get_class($oCodeGroup));
    }
    $this->oCodeGroup = $oCodeGroup;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the best way to do this is the Method 1.
Best you can do is testing the "good" case, and then check that every property produces a validation error when a invalid value is set.

This is a common xUnit pattern.

A way to archieve this is having a method that produces a valid object, and using it for testing all the cases.
For the non-valid cases, you can employ a [dataProvider](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) that will pass a setter method name and a value. For each case, you set that value and check that the object is not valid anymore.

Basically it's the same you were doing but in a more organized way:

```
private function getValidFixture()
{
    $fixture = $this->oObject();
    $this->oObject->setActionCodeGroupID(12);
    $this->oObject->setFilename('filename.txt');
    $this->oObject->setAmount(10000);
    $this->oObject->setMaxUsage(10);
    $this->oObject->setMinLength(9);
    $this->oObject->setMaxLength(12);
    $this->oObject->setPrefix('TM_');
    return $this->oObject;
}

public function testValidObject()
{
    $this->assertTrue($this->getValidFixture()->validate());
}

public function invalidProperties()
{
    return array(
         array(
             $setter = "setActionCodeGroupID",
             $value = 0
         ),
         array(
             $setter = "setFilename",
             $value = ""
         ),

         /** more setters ... */

    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider invalidProperties
 */
public function testInvalidObject($setter, $value)
{
     $fixture = $this->getValidFixture();
     $fixture->$setter($value);
     $this->assertFalse($fixture->validate());
}
```

Comment: Ah this does shed more light to the subject of making it easier to test. Especially the use of a dataProvider and splitting everything up. Thanks!

Comment: If you like the solution, you can always accept the answer :-)

Comment: Tried out the solution and works great. Considering the implementation of the class that's tested, this is a brilliant way of testing the validate method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 cannot fail with the exception you are throwing because it will fail PHP-side due to a violation of the type hinting. You can not pass a non-instance of CodeGroup into this function without PHP complaining. Note that you can make this parameter optional and are then allowed to explicitly also pass the default value, which must not conform to the type hint. That way you'll be able to allow NULL as a value, and are then burdened with the task to always check if you have an object of proper type, "otherwise do something else".

It is however a very good idea to use type hints. They will prevent you from passing the wrong object, and enable most IDEs to give you autocompletion support.

Now the problem I see with your approach to validation is that you have a huge amount of parameters all stuffed together, and now you'll need a huge amount of test cases checked properly. In a worst case, every single parameter has one range of values being valid, and two ranges above and below that are invalid. So for a single parameter, you have at least three test cases, maybe four (the smallest and biggest valid value, and the invalid value right next to that).

Adding a second parameter with the same amount of single tests multiplies the number of test cases. Now you need 9 or 16 test cases if you cannot check the parameters independently.

If you can check each parameter validation independently, you would need the three or four test cases for them (times 2 for two parameters), and an additional combination test case with one valid and one invalid parameter for both, which are 4 additional cases, to test the combinations of valid and invalid parameters are correctly combined. Which leaves you with 3 + 3 + 4 = 10 or 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 testcases instead of 9 or 16.

Enter a third parameter. Without individual tests you'd now have 3^3 = 27 test cases - with individual test cases you'd only need 3 * 3 + 2 ^ 3 = 17 test cases. And at this point you'd probably take advantage of the fact that your logic to combine X individual validation results into one with the general rule that every single validation must pass to make the whole validation pass is properly tested.

Now the task of validating an arbitrary combination of parameters has been split up into writing a specific validator for each parameter, and then combining all of them into one result.

And with that approach your tests will become much easier, because you'd split all these aspects into single tests.

Comment: Do keep in mind that method 2 was just an example, might not have been the best because I've employed typehinting, the principal however remains the same. Writing seperate validators for each setter isn't a bad idea, but why not validate inside the setter itself, and get rid of the combined result method (IE Object::validate())?